# Solution: How come that lxc-attach doesn't work within su -c?

Tags: sudo, su, lxc

I have an unprivileged lxc container. It works well and if I need to do something within that container, I `su --login lxc-user`, then I do `lxc-attach -e -n lxc-container` for e. g. doing updates manually as root therein. Sometimes I need to do something as the normal user of that linux container, then I do `su --login lxc-user`, then I do `lxc-attach -e -n lxc-container`, then I do `su --login normal-user` e. g. to add another crontab job.

I tried to script these steps but I encountered, that lxc-attach doesn't work within a su - c command. See, this works:

```
$me:~$ sudo su --login lxc-user
$lxc-user:~$ lxc-attach -e -n lxc-container -- ls -ld /home/normal-user
drwxr-xr-x 15 normal-user normal-user 4096 Aug 28 15:47 /home/normal-user
$lxc-user:~$
```

If I script that, it doesn't work, it even doesn't bark:

```
$me:~$ sudo su --login lxc-user -c 'lxc-attach -e -n lxc-container -- ls -ld /home/normal-user'
$me:~$
```

Is there an explanation why this can't work? Or is there even a solution for my problem?

Update:
Solution:

The reason it doesn't work is that it segfaults. If I do that I get e. g. from dmesg:

```
[Mo Aug 31 20:45:10 2020] 3[2089617]: segfault at 30 ip 00007fe174eb9e4c sp 00007ffdf0f99ef0 error 4 in libpthread-2.31.so[7fe174eb0000+10000]
[Mo Aug 31 20:45:10 2020] Code: ec 98 00 00 00 45 31 c0 64 48 8b 04 25 28 00 00 00 48 89 84 24 88 00 00 00 31 c0 48 85 f6 74 15 48 b9 00 00 00 80 01 00 00 00 <48> 8b 06 48 85 c8 75 44 49 89 f0 41 ba 08 00 00 00 4c 89 c6 b8 0e
```

I just don't know what exactly segfaults. I really have no clue.

Comment: Are you sure the command is not executed, but the output thrown away? I.e. Try executing a command in the guest that has a side-effect (e.g. creating a file in `/tmp`).

Comment: But you're confusing yourself (and everybody trying to help) with `sudo su`, your `-c <command>` is probably taken as an argument to `sudo`.

Comment: @Henrik I tried touching /tmp/file and checked afterword, there is no /tmp/file.

Comment: @Henrik I see no confusing. $me is an unprivileged user as $lxc-user is, but $me is allowed to sudo commands without password. suing to $lxc-user from $me asks for password if I don't sudo. $me:~$ sudo su --login lxc-user -c 'whoami' responds lxc-user back to the $me:~$ shell

Comment: 0

Try looking on the host for /tmp/file. I suspect you'll find it, and that will be a clear indication that the command was executed on the host, rather than on the guest. And I suspect that you have a "lxc-user" user on both the host and the guest.

Comment: No, there isn't. I tried again because a couple of day went by. The situation is the same.